# Fixed sidebar inside wrapping div

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, sidebar, css-position

Hi I've been trying to make a fixed sidebar inside wrapping div but yet have no luck. The page is http://www.rayshaft.com/sample.html and I need the sidebar to stay fixed while I scroll down the other news section. the section structure is like this:

```
<section class="secondary">
 <section id="sidebar">
 ...
 </section>
 <section id="othernews">
 ...
 </section>
```

I tried absolute positioning inside "secondary" section, fixed, that actually fixes the sidebar relatively to browser window, and I tried this query which seems to be exactly what i need: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/VtPcm/ but I couldn't make it work with my page. Any idea what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is kind of hard for us to analyze. Try breaking down the page until the desired effect works. Then build up again while keeping the effect.

Comment: may be there is another way for me to get the desired effect?

Comment: Well breaking down the page actually helped thanks. I guess I got messed somewhere in my html but I used this sample http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/VtPcm/ to build my page again and now everything works ok

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.position()` instead of `.offset()` and remove extra symbols from your end of script `â€‹`

```
$(function() {
    var top = $('#sidebar').position().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var footTop = $('#footer').position().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var maxY = footTop - $('#sidebar').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function(evt) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > top) {
        if (y < maxY) {
            $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed').removeAttr('style');
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed').css({
                 position: 'absolute',
                  top: (maxY - top) + 'px'
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
}); //â€‹ What are this symbols ???? remove them!
```